# Error checking pandas df column dtype on timestamp or string columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm checking the data type of all of my columns in a python pandas dataframe.
When I check the int64 or float64 columns, it works fine, like so:

```
print("df['Pass'][0].dtype=",df['Pass'][0].dtype)
```

output is `df['Pass'][0].dtype= int64`

However, when I try to check columns that should be timestamps or strings, I bomb out of the **try** block I'm in and go to the **except**:

```
print("df['DATETIME'][0]=",df['DATETIME'][0])
print("df['DATETIME'][0].dtype=",df['DATETIME'][0].dtype)
....
except: 
   print("FILE CORRUPTED...")
```

this gives me:
`df['DATETIME'][0]= 2021-01-25 14:14:08.535000+00:00 FILE CORRUPTED`

I get the same error if I check the .dtype of string columns as well.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by subsrpting with `[0]`, you are accessing the element type instead of the Series type.

Pandas Timestamp object (instead of the series) has no method / property of `dtype` while int64 has this property.  Hence you will get error: `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Similarly, for string type element (instead of series), it has no `dtype` property.  Hence, you will get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

For integer int64 elements, it does have this `dtype` property, and you will get e.g `dtype('int64')`

You could use `type()` function to get the element type, e.g:

```
type(df['DATETIME'][0])
```

would give you:  `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

This should work also for string, int and float (element types).